# Autoencoder for sound data in Keras

Tags: audio, keras, autoencoder

I have a 2d array of log-scaled mel-spectrograms of sound samples for 5 different categories.

For training I have used convolutional and dense neural network in Keras. Here the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(80, 8, activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(60,108)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2,padding='same',strides=None))
model.add(Flatten())
initializer=initializers.TruncatedNormal()
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',lr=0.01,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

What kind of autoencoder can I apply to this type of data input? What model? Any suggestion or also code example would be helpful. :)

Comment: I think that probably you can use convolutional 3D Keras layers, for example, you can start from a simple convolutional network with 16 3x3x3 kernels in the first layer and 16 5x5x5 kernels in second + add simple MLP with the softmax output. I will provide a precise answer with code sample for your data if you can share it. However, till then you can see a sample of CAE for image here in my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921246/issue-with-simple-cae

Comment: I shared my model, which has changed a bit now, since the input data is a 2d array. I look forward to receiving some suggestions from you. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using Conv1D for two dimensional data? I suggest using Conv2D since we have 2 dimensional data nature. It should give better result. However I can’t check it since not I don’t have data to check. 

However, I can suggest you some models to check with Conv2D if you not mind using Conv2d, but I can give you much more precise answer if I had data to test, because good model shall take into account the nature of the data

Comment: How can I share the data set with you? Sorry for the ignorance but I am new with stackoverflow.

Comment: You can upload it to google drive and share your file to everyone who has a link, then add this link to your question or post in the comment. However, I've already prepared probably not very precise answer based on my assumptions above about a nature of the data. So you can check it first, However, if you can’t build your model or prepare data for training successfully, please consider sharing your data by the link, so I’ll be able to help you with that

Comment: your help with my dataset would be great, also with the suggestion of the Conv2D. Here the link to my sound data: features (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B02xhizkrpq9V0VEdnh6d1poeEE), labels (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B02xhizkrpq9eVVXMmRjT0hSeEE)

Comment: Ok, will do. However I don't know how to open/read data from SoundDataX.msg and SoundDataY.msg, could you give me an example of code to open it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157716/discussion-between-emanuela-liaci-and-stepan-novikov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don’t have answers to my question about the nature of the data, I will assume that we have set of 2 dimensional data with the shape like (NSamples, 68, 108). Also, I assume that answer on my suggestion to use Convolutional2D instead Convolutional1D is yes

Here is sample of models for convolutional auto encoder, model, which can use a trained auto encoder and how to use weights from an auto encoder for the final model:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Conv2D, Deconv2D, MaxPooling1D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Conv2DTranspose, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import keras.models as models
import keras.initializers as initializers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

ae = models.Sequential()
#model.add(Conv1D(80, 8, activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(60,108)))
#encoder
c = Conv2D(80, 3, activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(60, 108, 1))
ae.add(c)
ae.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same', strides=None))
ae.add(Flatten())
initializer=initializers.TruncatedNormal()
d1 = Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer)
ae.add(d1)
ae.add(BatchNormalization())
ae.add(Dropout(0.8))
d2 = Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer)
ae.add(d2)
ae.add(Dropout(0.8))
#decodser
ae.add(Dense(d2.input_shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
ae.add(Dense(d1.input_shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
ae.add(Reshape((30, 54, 80)))
ae.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))
ae.add(Deconv2D(filters= c.filters, kernel_size= c.kernel_size, strides=c.strides, activation=c.activation, padding=c.padding, ))
ae.add(Deconv2D(filters= 1, kernel_size= c.kernel_size, strides=c.strides, activation=c.activation, padding=c.padding, ))
ae.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
optimizer='adam',lr=0.001,
metrics=['accuracy'])
ae.summary()
#now train your convolutional autoencoder to reconstruct your input data
#reshape your data to (NSamples, 60, 108, 1)
#Then train your autoencoder. it can be something like that:
#X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=43)
#pre_mcp = ModelCheckpoint("CAE.hdf5", monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=2, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
#pre_history = ae.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_val, X_val), batch_size=22, verbose=2, callbacks=[pre_mcp])

#model
model = models.Sequential()
#model.add(Conv1D(80, 8, activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(60,108)))
model.add(Conv2D(80, 3, activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(60, 108, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same',strides=None))
model.add(Flatten())
initializer=initializers.TruncatedNormal()
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer='adam',lr=0.001,
metrics=['accuracy'])
#Set weights              
model.layers[0].set_weights(ae.layers[0].get_weights())       
model.layers[3].set_weights(ae.layers[3].get_weights())  
model.layers[4].set_weights(ae.layers[4].get_weights())  
model.layers[6].set_weights(ae.layers[6].get_weights())  
model.summary()
#Now you can train your model with pre-trained weights from autoencoder
```

A model like this was useful for me with MNIST dataset and improved accuracy of model with initial weights from auto encoder in comparison with model initialized with random weights

However, I would recommend using of several convolutional/deconvolutional layers, probably 3 or more, since from my experience convolutional auto encoders with 3 and more convolutional layers are more efficient than with 1 convolutional layer. In fact, with one convolutional layer I can’t even see any accuracy improvements sometimes

*Update:*

I checked auto encoder with data provided by Emanuela, also I checked it with different auto encoders architectures without any success

My hypothesis about that is that the data doesn’t contain any significant features, which can be distinguished by auto encoder or even CAE

However, it looks like my assumption about 2 dimensional nature of the data was confirmed by reaching of almost 99.99% validation accuracy:
[image]

Nevertheless, in the same time, 97.31% accuracy of training data can indicate potential issues with dataset, so it looks like a good idea to revise it

In addition, I would suggest using ensembles of networks. You could train, for example 10 networks with different validation data and assign a category for items by the most voted categories

Here is my code:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import keras.models as models
import keras.initializers as initializers
import msgpack
import numpy as np

with open('SoundDataX.msg', "rb") as fx,open('SoundDataY.msg', "rb") as fy: 
    dataX=msgpack.load(fx) 
    dataY=msgpack.load(fy)

num_samples = len(dataX)
x = np.empty((num_samples, 60, 108, 1), dtype = np.float32)
y = np.empty((num_samples, 4), dtype = np.float32)

for i in range(0, num_samples):
    x[i] = np.asanyarray(dataX[i]).reshape(60, 108, 1)
    y[i] = np.asanyarray(dataY[i])

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=43)

#model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(60, 108, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 5, activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(60, 108, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 7, activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(60, 108, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
initializer=initializers.TruncatedNormal()
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer=initializer,bias_initializer=initializer))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),
metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
filepath="weights-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.7f}-{acc:.7f}.hdf5"
mcp = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=2, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), batch_size=64, verbose=2, callbacks=[mcp])
```